# Non-manifold edges even after cleaning up (doubles, internal faces, etc.)

Tags: edges, 3d-printing

I hope all is well. I have a fairly simply 3D design that's been bugging me for the last 3 hours or so (I've attached a hopefully informative picture to this post).

The highlighted edges in the picture are non manifold, and I can't tell why. There are no internal faces, no double vertices, no "zero-volum" spaces.

Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I used the "3D Printing" toolbar.

Comment: Can you try *Select > Select All by Trait > Non Manifold* and see if it selects these edges? Might a bug in the 3D printing add-on.

Comment: While trying going to Select > Select All by Trait, I only have the following options: Loose Geometry, Faces by Sides, and Internal Faces (perhaps because I'm using blender 2.8?).

Comment: You need to be in vertex or edge select mode.

Comment: Got it. I can't paste a picture here apparently, but the same vertices are highlighted.

Comment: Oh I think I see what the problem is. The circle is part of the same mesh, right? It's not properly connected or where it is there are faces with zero thickness.

Comment: Got it. I'll check that right after I get back to my office

Comment: I just did the whole thing again, this time making it from "one piece."

it worked.